# SAM alignment: Extract specific region in the query sequence and its enclosing parts in the CIGAR string

Tags: python, bioinformatics, text-processing

I need to perform the local alignment of a given region of a DNA sequence for which a global alignment was made, and update the corresponding part of the global CIGAR string.

The steps would be as follow:

**1.** Extract the region of interest from the "query" sequence according to the CIGAR string of the global alignment.

**2.** Perform the local alignment of the region and generate the local CIGAR string.

**3.** Extract from the global CIGAR string the operations "before" and "after" the region of interest.

**4.** Generate the new global CIGAR string

I would like to get help for **#1** and **#3**

Here's a concrete example:

```
Input:
------
Reference sequence: ACGGCATCAGCGATCATCGGCATATCGAC (against which the global alignment was made)
Query sequence:     TCATCAAGCGTCGCCCTC
CIGAR string:       1S5M1I3M4D6M2D2M
CIGAR position:     5 (1-based, position of the leftmost mapped nucleotide in the reference)
Genomic region:     7-23 (1-based, inclusive)
```

And the interpretation of the above data:

```
Reference:   ACGGCA|TCA-GCGATCATCGGCAT|ATCGAC
Query:          .CA|TCAAGCG----TCGCCC-|-TC
CIGAR*:         SMM|MMMIMMMDDDDMMMMMMD|DMM
Position:        ↑
```

<sup>**note:** the genomic region is in between the `|` characters</sup>

So, in this example I would need to extract `TCAAGCGTCGCCC` from  `Query` and `SMM` & `DMM` from `CIGAR*`.

---

Here's my clumsy attempt:

```py
import re
import itertools

# Input:
reference = 'ACGGCATCAGCGATCATCGGCATATCGAC'
query     = 'TCATCAAGCGTCGCCCTC'
cigar     = '1S5M1I3M4D6M2D2M'
region    = (7-1, 23)
position  = 5-1

# Now trying the extract the region in the query and the outer parts of the CIGAR:
x0, x1 = region       # range in reference
y0, y1 = (None, None) # range in query
c0, c1 = ([], [])     # cigar operations, before and after the region
x      = position     # current position in reference
y      = 0            # current position in query

for op in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(m[1], int(m[0])) for m in re.findall(r'(\d+)([MIDS])', cigar)):

    if x < x0: 
        c0.append(op)
    elif x < x1:
        if y0 == None:
            y0 = y 
        else:
            y1 = y 
    else:
        c1.append(op)

    if op == 'M':
        x += 1
        y += 1
    elif op in ['S','I']:
        y += 1
    elif op == 'D':
        x += 1

y1 += 1

print( (''.join(c0), query[y0:y1], ''.join(c1)) )
```

```
('SMM', 'TCAAGCGTCGCCCT', 'DMM')
```

The problem is that I get a superfluous `T` at the end of the query region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only when encountering an operation that increments `y` should you update `y0` and `y1`. Here you would need to exclude `D`, but you can make a more generic code by storing the increments of an operation in a `dict`:

```py
increments = {
    'M': {'x': 1, 'y': 1},
    'I': {'x': 0, 'y': 1},
    'D': {'x': 1, 'y': 0},
    'S': {'x': 0, 'y': 1},
}

for op in itertools.chain.from_iterable(
    itertools.repeat(m[1], int(m[0]))
    for m in re.findall(r'(\d+)([MIDS])', cigar)
):

    if x < x0: 
        c0.append(op)
    elif x < x1:
        if increments[op]['y']:
            if y0 == None:
                y0 = y 
            y1 = y+1 
    else:
        c1.append(op)

    x += increments[op]['x']
    y += increments[op]['y']

print( (''.join(c0), query[y0:y1], ''.join(c1)) )
```

```py
('SMM', 'TCAAGCGTCGCCC', 'DMM')
```